# Swift Extended iterable unpacking of tuples

Tags: swift, tuples

We know in Python you can do

```
s = (3,5,2)
a, *b = s # a=3 b=[5,2]
```

That is, you can unpack let's say the first element of the tuple and *the rest*.

I'm struggling to find the same in Swift:

```
var tuple = ("Boston", "Red Sox", 97, 65, 59.9)
var (first, rest) = tuple
```

Comment: Despite sharing the same names, Python tuples and Swift tuples are almost nothing alike. Pythons tuples are just immutable lists, which is just like a Swift array declared with `let`. Swift’s tuples are strongly (and structurally typed). Without variadic generics, it’s not really possible to do any useful “first/rest” functional-style processing of them. An array would be more suited to the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none (at the moment), Swift is strongly typed. i.e the compiler has to know this information - you can write a function that does the unpacking though.

```
func unpack(tuple: (String, String, Double, Double, Double)) -> (String, (String, Double, Double, Double)) {
  return (tuple.0,(tuple.1, tuple.2, tuple.3, tuple.4))
}
```

In case you have more than two/three elements in a tuple it is recommended to group them under some model.

Answer (score 2):

You could make some generic functions to do it:

```
func firstRest<A, B, C>(_ tup: (A, B, C)) -> (A, (B, C)) {
    (tup.0, (tup.1, tup.2))
}

func firstRest<A, B, C, D>(_ tup: (A, B, C, D)) -> (A, (B, C, D)) {
    (tup.0, (tup.1, tup.2, tup.3))
}

func firstRest<A, B, C, D, E>(_ tup: (A, B, C, D, E)) -> (A, (B, C, D, E)) {
    (tup.0, (tup.1, tup.2, tup.3, tup.4))
}

func firstRest<A, B, C, D, E, F>(_ tup: (A, B, C, D, E, F)) -> (A, (B, C, D, E, F)) {
    (tup.0, (tup.1, tup.2, tup.3, tup.4, tup.5))
}
```

Now you can:

```
let tuple = ("Boston", "Red Sox", 97, 65, 59.9)
let (first, rest) = firstRest(tuple)
print(first)
print(rest)
```